# Using map with function that has multiple arguments

Tags: list, haskell, higher-order-functions, map-function, partial-application

Is it possible to use map with a function that takes multiple arguments?

I want to use map's second and third arguments repeatedly as the function's arguments. 
As in

```
mapF x y z = map (f y z) [1, 2, 3]
```

So it'll evaluate `f` with the same `y` and `z` values, but with `x = 1`, `x = 2`, `x = 3` and so on.

Comment: Use a lambda: `map (\x -> f x y z) [1, 2, 3]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use a lambda function, to see this works lets start by using a helper function to map f over some list.

```
map helper [1, 2, 3] where
  helper x = f x y z
```

In Haskell there are two syntax for functions so lets use the lambda syntax to define our helper function:

```
map helper [1, 2, 3] where
  helper = \x -> f x y z
```

using the lambda syntax we don't need to give our helper function an explicit name, it can just be an anonymous function we map over the input

```
map (\x -> f x y z) [1, 2, 3]
```

So now you can say

```
mapF y z = map (\x -> f x y z) [1,2,3]
```

But presumably you don't want `x` to be 1, 2 and 3, you want it to be a list
you pass as an argument to `mapF`. So you need to give that a different name:

```
mapF xs y z = map (\x -> f x y z) xs
```

It is Haskell convention to use `s` as a suffix for variables that hold lists or other containers. So if one value is `x` then a list of them is `xs`

Answer (score 4):

There are guaranteed to be better ways to do this (still learning) but you can:

```
f' = map f [1,2,3]
```

`f'` is now a list of partially applied `f`

```
g y z= map (\h -> h y z) f'
```

will take each of those functions and run it on the arguments y z.

You can hack that all in one line.

Comment: I don't get it. f won't work with only one argument.

Comment: Haskell is perfectly fine with only partially applying a function, it just makes a function which needs more arguments. For example if you say f = (2+) that makes a function which needs another argument so f 6 = 8, f 10 = 12 etc. .

Comment: I'm confirming that this works, though I think Bi Rico's answer is more simple and intuitive.